# Queuing form submission requests until server has returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a backbone based view where the user can type a word in a text field and submit the form. There are two events associated with the view - `submit` and `keyup`.

```
class NewConceptView extends Backbone.View
  el: '#new-concept-cont'
  template: JST['concepts/new']

  events:
    'submit form': 'handleSubmit'
    'keyup #concept_title' : 'getPossibilities'
```

As the user types, I need to hit my server and request some data (referred to as `possibilities`) about what the user is typing (just like an autocomplete plugin).

```
getPossibilities: (e) ->
  currentText = @titleInput.val() 
  if currentText.length > 0
    params = { text: currentText }
    $.getJSON(url, params, @buildConceptAttrs)
```

Then when the user submits the form, I need to take the last possibilities from the server and add them to a collection.

```
handleSubmit: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  @titleInput.val('')
  @collection.create(@conceptAttrs)
```

The problem I'm having occurs when I type fast into the text box and then hit submit. Basically, the form gets submitted before all of the possibilities requests to the server have returned.

Is there a way that I should be queuing submit events so that they don't occur before all the requests for possibilities have returned?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there a way that I should be queuing submit events
```

Well, I don't know about *should*, but the basic approach I'd use would be:

1. When you initialize your view, set this.outstanding_callbacks = 0;
2. Just before you make your $.getJSON call, increment that var (this.outstanding_callbacks++)
3. In @buildConceptAttrs decrement that var (this.outstanding_callbacks--)
4. When you go to submit, check the outstanding_callbacks; if it's > 0, don't submit.  Instead, do a window.setTimeout(5000, retryFunction), where 5000 is however many milliseconds you want to wait and retryFunction is basically the same function (it might literally be the same function)

Now, you may have to do some binding or something so that you have access to the view in steps #3 and #4, but hopefully that gives you a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

I capture the [jQuery.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart) and [jQuery.ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop) events.

I show a *loading* message:

```
$(function(){
  $('#loading').ajaxStart( function() {
    $(this).animate({ top: "0" }, 200);
  });

  $('#loading').ajaxStop( function() {
    $(this).animate({ top: "-70" }, 100);
  });
});
```

But taking the idea you can use same technique to disable the `form.submit()`, or at least wait for the `.ajasStop()` to execute the submit.

It is not really waiting for all the events in process.. just for the *AJAX* ones.. but maybe it solves your problem enough.